# SQL Server do I need two queries and a function efficiency question

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I want to get a list of people affiliated with a blog. The table `[BlogAffiliates]` has:

- `BlogID`
- `UserID`
- `Privelage`

and if the persons associated with that blog have a lower or equal privelage they cannot edit `[bit field canedit]`.

Is this query the most efficient way of doing this or are there better ways to derive this information??

I wonder if it can be done in a single query??

Can it be done without that convert in some more clever way?

```
declare @privelage tinyint
select @privelage = (select Privelage from BlogAffiliates 
            where UserID=@UserID and BlogID = @BlogID)

select aspnet_Users.UserName as username,
   BlogAffiliates.Privelage as privelage,
       Convert(Bit, Case When @privelage> blogaffiliates.privelage 
                    Then 1 Else 0 End) As canedit 
from BlogAffiliates, aspnet_Users 
where BlogAffiliates.BlogID = @BlogID and BlogAffiliates.Privelage >=2 
        and aspnet_Users.UserId = BlogAffiliates.UserID
```

Comment: It should be spelled `privilege` ....

Comment: I like the idea of how one privilege can cane the other into allowing the person to edit the piece of info. Basically, if your privilege *caned it*, you *can edit*. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of this would depend on the indexs and the size of the tables involved. If for example your most costly portion of the query when you profiled it was a seek on the "BlogAffiliates.BlogID" column, then you could do one select into a table variable and then do both calculations from there.

However I think most likely the query you have stated is probably going to be close the the most efficient. The only possible work duplication is you are seeking twice on the "BlogAffiliates.BlogID" fields because of the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

```
Select aspnet_Users.UserName as username, Blog.Privelage as privelage,
Convert(Bit, Case When @privelage> Blog.privelage 
    Then 1 Else 0 End) As canedit 
From
(
    Select UserID, Privelage
    From BlogAffiliates
    Where BlogID = @BlogID and Privelage >= 2
)Blog
Inner Join aspnet_Users on aspnet_Users.UserId = Blog.UserID
```

As per my understanding you should not use **Table variable**, in case you are joining it with other table. This can **reduce the performance**. But in case the records are less, then you should go for it. You can also use **Local temporary tables** for this purpose.

Comment: Again with the Table variables it all depends on what indexes are involved, the size of the tables,  and the size of the results in the table variable. Table variable can be slow(er) on a join only if they are not indexed (A table variable can have a primary key defined which creates an index). Even without an index, if your table variable not large, the "table scan" work done in memory is actually faster. Especially if the tables and indexes you are working with can't be cached entirely in memory consistently. It is an incorrect blanket statement that table variables reduce performance.

Comment: Hi Xenophile, Here, we want to suggest other person that the table join will not be 100%, It will be one percent only , as we have where clause. And Moreover we are using the Sub query here for Table Variable. It should increase the performance.